# Selenium - How to send a jQuery from inside an iframe?

Tags: python, jquery, json, selenium

I have been using Selenium Webdriver for Python to automate some daily tasks at my job. Wanting to learn more, I have been using Selenium to write some scripts in my spare time. I have had some success, but recently, while trying to make a bot for neopets.com to run daily activities, I encountered a scenario that I have not been able to get any traction in automating.

The minigame is basically just a randomly determined slot game called Trudy's surprise (url: http://www.neopets.com/trudys_surprise.phtml, you may have to make an account to access it). The function I am trying to accomplish is just to click the "Play" button with Selenium, or otherwise have the slot game execute. While this function is pretty trivial, it seems to me (maybe because I can't crack it on my own) that there is a learning experience here because the solution is not as simple as using `webelem.click()` as far as I can tell.

I have been using the Inspect function of Chrome to look at the underlying script of the game. If you navigate to the slots game, right-click anywhere in the game frame, and click "inspect" a console should show up with a `<canvas>` element highlighted. This `<canvas>` element is inside an `<iframe>`, which I will refer to throughout this post.

So here are the problems I am facing (AKA things I've tried that don't work):

I cannot get an xpath for the button because the game itself is inside an iframe. I have tried going through a list of all elements in the iframe using the `driver.switch_to.frame()` function then doing a `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")`, and only found the html elements described in the page (no start button).

Since I couldn't find the element, I figured I would try to replicate its effects. The source script for the slot machine is located at http://www.neopets.com/trudydaily/js/slotsgame.js?v=1525633042. I would copy it here but it is quite long. I have almost no experience with html or Javascript, but it seems like this script is called in the header of the iframe by

```
<script src="/trudydaily/js/slotsgame.js?v=1525633042">
</script>
```

creating a SlotsGame object which is then called by a script in the body of the iframe. The SlotsGame object only has three callable member functions: Initialize, LoadAssets, and Start. It also looks like the script posts a jQuery and waits for a response from the server, allowing the user to either spin or not based on the response. The script which calls the SlotsGame object looks like

```
  var ajaxurl = '/trudydaily/ajax/claimprize.php';
  //var data = {'action': 'getslotstate'};
  var data = {
    'action': 'getslotstate','key': '2nA6BqsTIM1IT785Di08dqyFKnLCM1M7VTcOfSnC41I%3D'};
  var resp;
  parent.$.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response){
    resp = JSON.parse(response);
                if(resp.error == ""){
          SlotsGame.LoadAssets(AssetLoadComplete, "http://images.neopets.com");
        }
      else{
        parent.CloseSlotsGame();
      }
            }
    );
    SlotsGame.Initialize();
    function AssetLoadComplete(){
      SlotsGame.Start(resp);
    }
    function CloseGame(){
      parent.CloseSlotsGame();
    };
```

with the `key` value changing each time the page is loaded.

Calls to `driver.execute_script("SlotsGame.LoadAssets()")` and `...Initialize()...` both work when called from within the context of the iframe (they create a copy of the slots game in the iframe), so I know I am on the right track. However, I have tried executing `SlotsGame.Start(i)` for `i=1,2,3` from within the context of the iframe and no dice (or not slots). I have also tried executing the entire above script using `driver.execute_script(webelem.get_attribute('innerHTML'))`, but nothing happens.

I'm sure that I am missing an easy way to automatically activate this machine, but I have tried almost everything I can think of with no success.

Apologies for any imprecise terminology or similar, I am still trying to pick this skill up. I am hoping that someone who understands html, Javascript, and JSON will understand the issue. Please let me know if you can think of a way I can edit the question to make it more precise or generally applicable. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This would be really simple if only Selenium made post requests easy.. luckily there is a package for that! https://github.com/cryzed/Selenium-Requests

```
import re
import time
from seleniumrequests import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

# Selenium-Requests way of launching a browser instance
browser = Firefox()
```

then after your login stuff,

```
browser.get("http://www.neopets.com/trudys_surprise.phtml")     

# Waits for trudys iframe to be loaded, and then switches to the iframe
wait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("frameTest"))
time.sleep(1)

# gets key from the iframe page_source; not the worlds best regex   
matchobj = re.search(r"\'action\'\: \'\w*\',\'key\'\: \'(.*)\'\}\;", str(browser.page_source))

if(matchobj):
    key = str(matchobj.group(1))    
    postPage = ('http://www.neopets.com/trudydaily/ajax/claimprize.php')

    response = browser.request('POST', postPage, data={'action':'getslotstate','key':key})
    time.sleep(2)

    response = browser.request('POST', postPage, data={'action':'beginroll'})
    time.sleep(2)

    response = browser.request('POST', postPage, data={'action':'prizeclaimed'})
    time.sleep(2)   

    # switches back from the iframe to the main window
    browser.switch_to.default_content()
```